# How to pass dynamic list values in increment one by one in functions according to the user input in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to solve one logic but not getting the exact behavior.PF the scenario :

First script will run and it shows number of devices.Assume:

```
1) Device 1 (x=1, y=x)
2) Device 2 (x=2, y=y)
3) Device 3 (x=4, y=Z)
4) ........
5) ........
```

Now after that i am taking input from user such as index - 1,2,3.PF:

input = raw_input('Which device you want:')

Now after getting the values i will append all the values in empty list in a=[] , b=[]

The values will be stored in two dynamic lists according to the operations.Lets say:

a=[1,2,4,5,6...]
b=[x,y,z,g,h...]

Now after taking input for device,the script will again ask for input .PF:

input = raw_input('Enter operation you want to perform in device from below operations:')

Output :
1) Get Report
2) Get Sample

Expected Behavior :According to input it should perform some operation.Operation depends on list values.

- Suppose user enter: 2

Now script should take value 2 from a and y from b

- Suppose user enter:4

Now script should take value 5 from a and g from b

- Suppose user enter:1

Now script should take value 1 from a and x from b

and so on.....

```
a=[1,2,4,5,6...] -> The list is dynamic
b=[x,y,z,g,h...] -> The list is dynamic
input = raw_input('Enter your input:')
if input == 1:
   verify = report(a[],b[])  --> How to pass here values of a and b if user presses 1?
   return verify
elif input == 2:
    verify = sample(a[],b[]) --> How to pass here values of and b if user presses 2
    return verify


def report(first,second):
    print first
    print second

def sample(third,fourth):
    print third
    print fourth
```

How can i achieve this behavior described above?

Comment: `x = int(input); report(a[x-1],b[x-1])` ?

Comment: its always giving me 1st value.When i am pressing 2 the value I am getting is still the same as i get from 1st .i.e 1,x but ideally it should give 2,y when i move to 2nd.

Comment: Yes i did similar thing but i think we are missing the concept here.When script 1st run it show some devices associated with a and b .Then i am appending the values of a and b in some list .So when user enter the device number 2 i.e index .It should behave according to device placed at index number 2 . & fetch the value from list and do the operation.See my edit please